# nodejs map return nothing when if statement true

Tags: node.js, if-statement, return

so i have the following code

```js
data.push(commands.map(
    command => {
        if (!command.devOnly) { return command.name; } // first condition
        if (command.devOnly && message.author.id != '3251268789058714880') {} // second condition
    },
).join('\n'));
```

if the second condition is true it returns `null` but then when I run `console.log(data)` it has a blank line for all the commands where the second condition is true.

Is there a way to stop the second condition from returning anything, and not leaving the blank line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.map()` is a 1-for-1 transformation so the output array will have EXACTLY the same number of elements in it as the input array.  If you don't return anything, that element in the array will have an `undefined` value (which is the return value when you don't actively return something).

To transform the array and eliminate some elements, you cannot use `.map()`.   You can either do `.filter().map()` where you first filter out the items you don't want and then map the others or you can use a regular `for` loop and just push the items into output array that you want to keep using either a regular `for` loop iteration or a `.reduce()` or `.forEach()` iteration.

One example:

```
const results = commands.filter(command => !command.devOnly).map(command => command.name);
console.log(results);

const results = [];
for (let command of commands) {
    if (!command.devOnly) results.push(command.name);
}
console.log(results);
```

Note, your second condition doesn't do anything at all in your code example so I wasn't sure how to account for that in these examples.

P.S. I've often wished Javascript had a `.filterMap()` feature that let you return `undefined` to leave that value out of the result - otherwise work like `.map()`.  But, it doesn't have that feature built in.  You could build your own.

---

Per your comments, you can filter on two conditions like this:

```
const results = commands
   .filter(command => !command.devOnly || message.author.id === '3251268789058714880')
   .map(command => command.name);
console.log(results);
```

Comment: would there be a way to modify the code in `.filter()` to include the code from my second condition, where it includes it IF the `message.author.id` is a specific value?

Comment: @Nodejs-nerd - Your second condition doesn't do anything.  What do you want that condition to do?  Sure, it's possible to modify the `.filter()` if I know what that condition is supposed to do.  It needs some action inside the `{}` after the `if`.

Comment: just realised it doesn't do anything, leftovers from testing. so, if the command is devonly and the `message.author.id` is a value (my id) then it should add it, if it is devonly and `message.author.id` is not my id then don't add it

Comment: @Nodejs-nerd - I added an example to the end of my answer of a `.filter()` with two conditions.  This will include the item if it is `!command.devOnly` or if the `message.author.id` is one specific value.  You can obviously modify that condition logic to suit whatever purpose you have.

Comment: okay, i think i should be able to make the changes from here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you could use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
commands.reduce((prev,command)=>{

  if (!command.devOnly) 
     return [...prev,command.name]
  // this if, is useless but shows that you can use more conditions.
  if (command.devOnly && message.author.id != '3251268789058714880') 
     return prev

  // add more conditions as you need here
  return prev


},[])
```

---

another options could be by doing map then filter the undefined values, or use for-loop
like jfriend00 explained in his answer. the `filterMap()` he wished could be implemented with `Array.reduce`